# plot multiple line segments on one graph using R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I duplicate this style of graph, with multiple plots on one graph, and, preferably, legends attached as below.

I have tried the concept of "facet" but ggplot2 and trellis:xyplot both think of facets as separate panels rather than overlaid plots.

I can do it using plain Jane plot() and line().. but was using ggplot2 and woudl like to get multiple lines on one plot in that package.

Here is some example data in long form (captured from the plot using a nifty app called "Graphclick")

```
comp <- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), header=T, sep=',')

company, year, sales
Apple,1975.003,17298.457
Apple,1977.302,16784.502
Apple,1978.314,17298.457
Apple,1980.246,20730.098
Apple,1981.533,27608.426
Apple,1984.293,40862.852
Apple,1986.408,50468.617
Apple,1987.328,48236.188
Apple,1988.892,35676.547
Apple,1989.904,34616.582
Apple,1991.192,44732.742
Apple,1992.387,44732.742
Apple,1993.399,39055.324
Apple,1995.791,37894.922
Apple,1996.895,39648.746
Apple,1998.274,52804.367
Apple,1999.378,61399.512
Apple,2001.770,2.350e5
Apple,2005.265,7.735e5
Toshiba,1999.378,86856.6
Toshiba,2001.862,1.192e5
Toshiba,2004.069,1.495e5
Toshiba,2004.069,1.495e5
IBM,1975.003,22019.092
IBM,1975.830,27195.193
IBM,1976.934,30682.320
IBM,1978.130,31148.527
IBM,1980.430,35676.547
IBM,1981.625,35676.547
IBM,1983.005,39648.746
IBM,1985.305,40862.852
IBM,1986.408,46102.508
IBM,1987.512,64241.156
IBM,1989.996,75832.898
IBM,1991.100,84276.039
IBM,1992.295,85556.641
IBM,1993.307,79342.539
IBM,1994.779,79342.539
IBM,1995.791,84276.039
IBM,1996.895,95082.484
IBM,1996.895,95082.484
Commodore,1975.003,33588.051
Commodore,1975.830,34616.582
Commodore,1977.118,25219.982
Commodore,1978.130,23388.229
Commodore,1979.326,25992.234
Commodore,1980.521,21689.514
Commodore,1981.717,25219.982
Commodore,1984.201,6999.029
Commodore,1985.213,1670.460
Commodore,1986.408,1458.447
```

[image: computing over time]
<sub>(source: [asymco.com](http://www.asymco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Screen-Shot-2012-01-18-at-1-18-4.31.31-PM.png))</sub>

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what's the problem. Why do you want to use facets at all? I don't see any facets or panels in the graph you are trying to duplicate. Example code a data would be useful

Comment: The only reason `ggplot2` would create facets is if you explicitly told it to. You probably just want to omit any reference to facets in your code and use `geom_line` setting the `group` aesthetic to the 'computer maker' variable. But more generally, I don't understand how you expect to get decent help without posting your data and code.

Comment: data added.can get multiple plots using the group aesthetic and geom_Line. Thanks!

    ggplot(data=comp, aes(year, sales, group = company)) + geom_line()

Now just need log Y axis, colors for each plot, and labels on the plot

Comment: Hi @tim, can you share the rest of that data? Or, provide a link to where I can find it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @user3062148, I don't recall where the sample came from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so, in ggplot2, this code works

```
qplot(year, sales, data=comp, colour=as.factor(company), group= company, geom="path", log="y")
```

The only things left now is to format the value on the Y axis as numeric (not sci notation), and the labels are in an off-graph legend, rather than on the plots... Final suggestions welcomed.

This is a lot easier in the end than plot() + lines(), as that required support code to get the ranges, iterate over the group levels etc.

[image]

Comment: If this is a comment, I would suggest you append it to your question (and delete this answer). If it's a (definite) answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark below the answer score.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for the most control, you could just use the low-level plot and lines commands. Use "plot" to generate the first graph (with title, xlimits, and ylimits), then use "lines" to add lines to that graph.

```
plot(0,type="n", xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), xlab="X Label", ylab="Y Label", main="Title")
```

Then add lines using the lines command:

```
lines(1:10, 1:10, type="l", lty=2)
lines(2:4, 10:8, col=2, type="l")
lines(6:9, c(5,6,5,6), col=3, type="l")
```

You can fine-tune the look by using all of the parameters listed in the "par" help file ("?par")

[image: Output of commands]

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I had a solution like this with plot... maybe that's the simplest AND best way to carry on :-)